# La locuzione “a giro”

Tags: idioms

Mi capita ogni tanto di sentire la locuzione “a giro” nel senso in cui a me sarebbe più familiare “in giro” (per esempio “sono a giro a fare shopping”).

Sia la voce [“giro” del Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giro) che [quella del De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/giro), quest'ultimo particolarmente attento alle espressioni polirematiche, danno ampio spazio a “in giro”, mentre non contemplano “a giro” (se non in contesti che non c'entrano, come “a giro collo”).

La mia domanda è: dove è diffuso “a giro”? In certe parti d'Italia, in certi ambiti sociali, altro?

<sup>Mi interessano risposte argomentate e dotate di fonti, non “io sono di XXX e dalle mie parti si dice/non si dice”, che può essere eventualmente interessante per un commento.</sup>

Comment: Io l'ho sempre considerata un toscanismo - quando abitavo a Pisa prendevamo sempre in giro i toscani perché la usavano.

Comment: Mai sentita questa locuzione, comunque ci sono alcuni esempi : “*Sono passati altri tre mesi e sono a giro per Pontassieve. Sento chiamarmi: «Marco! Marco!» Mi volto e riconosco Modiano, il mio vicino di casa, e gli domando: «Ciao, come ti va? Tutto bene in famiglia?»*” Da Un toscano qualunque: https://books.google.it/books?id=KJk-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT71&dq=%22sono+a+giro%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2fWTlN7-AhVhSvEDHYbfAfoQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22sono%20a%20giro%22&f=false

Comment: “*Facevano il giro delle ville e in villa Ginori il marchese pigliava l'ombrellino e accompagnava i ' prete pe ' tutto i ' giardino . i ' E tutti i tabernacoli che ci sono a giro , di maggio venivano abbelliti con i fiori , venivan fatte ...*” https://books.google.it/books?id=xpDZAAAAIAAJ&q=%22sono+a+giro%22&dq=%22sono+a+giro%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2fWTlN7-AhVhSvEDHYbfAfoQ6AF6BAgDEAM#%22sono%20a%20giro%22

Comment: “*oppure avviarti verso una professione, nobile quanto vuoi, ma piena di incertezze visti i fumi di guerra che ci sono a giro. Fai tu...» La mattina del 28 aprile Primo uscì dalla canonica che ancora non aveva preso una decisione.*” https://books.google.it/books?id=fkuEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&dq=%22sono+a+giro%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_2fWTlN7-AhVhSvEDHYbfAfoQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22sono%20a%20giro%22&f=false

Comment: ZONZO: “A zonzo” significa andare a giro. vocabolario pisano-italiano  https://www.travelstales.it/2016/05/27/sei-pisano-se-vocabolario-pisano/

Comment: Questo sito sul pisano è curioso, visto che registra “a zonzo” come se fosse pisano, mentre è [italiano standard](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zonzo), e usa per definirlo una locuzione che invece non lo è.

Comment: Si, è curiosa la definizione di a zonzo….andare a giro.